# Link Docker Container across the Host

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-network

My SetUP is as Below

Machine - 1 = couch docker

Machine - 2 = Web Docker

How do I connect / link my Web docker to another systems couch docker?

I tried Below method, but it isn't working.

On Machine-1

step-1

```
docker network create mynet
```

Step -2

```
docker run -v /home/user1/db:/var/lib/couchdb -p 0.0.0.0:5984:5984 --net mynet --name couch couch:latest
```

On Machine-2

Step - 3

```
 docker run  -e DB_URL=http://admin:admin@couch:5984/dbname --link couch:couch  -p 0.0.0.0:3000:3000 --net mynet --name web myweb:lates
```

It gives me below error

```
docker: Error response from daemon: network mynet not found.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

Any Idea what can be done?